# variable length substring of a string with specific beginning and ending

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula

I have to extract a substring which is always variable in length from within the middle of a string (cell) in excel.

The criteria is:

- it is always starting with a specific set of symbols (in this example "Ingredients:")
- it is always ending with a specific set of symbols (in this example "Table of Nutritional Information").

The length can be any from 1 word to about 500.

It could be an excel formula or even VBA. But I am a complete beginner with VBA, so please give specific advice there.

My example cell content is like this:

```
    We could tell you that our Beanz are hard to beat. That they're brimming with deliciously rich, tomatoey flavour. But you already know that. Because you know what Beanz Meanz...

Heinz baked beans don't just taste great, but are nutritious too; high in fibre, high in protein and low in fat, as well as contributing to 1 of your 5 a day. Packed full of quality ingredients... it has to be Heinz. Love our Heinz Beanz as much as we do? Discover the rest of our range, including organic and no added sugar varieties!

Heinz Beanz come in a variety of multipacks, perfect for when you need to feed the whole family!

1 of your 5 a day.
No artificial colours, flavours or preservatives.
Suitable for Vegetarians and Vegans.
Naturally high in protein and fibre.
Gluten free and low in fat.

Ingredients: 
Beans (51%), Tomatoes (34%), GRAIN, Water, Sugar, Spirit Vinegar, Modified Corn Flour, Salt, Spice Extracts, Herb Extract. 

Suitable for Vegetarians. Free From Artificial Flavours. 
Empty unused contents into a suitable covered container. Keep refrigerated and use within 2 days. 

 
Table of Nutritional Information
    Per 100g    Per 1/2 can %RI*
Energy  329kJ   682kJ   -
78kcal  162kcal 8%
Fat     0.2g    0.4g    1%
- of which saturates    <0.1g   <0.1g   <1%
Carbohydrate    12.5g   25.9g   10%
- of which sugars   4.7g    9.8g    11%
Fibre   3.7g    7.7g    -
Protein     4.7g    9.7g    19%
Salt    0.6g    1.2g    21%
*RI per serving. Reference intake of an average adult (8400kJ/2000kcal)
```

The desired outcome would be:

```
    Ingredients: 
Beans (51%), Tomatoes (34%), GRAIN, Water, Sugar, Spirit Vinegar, Modified Corn Flour, Salt, Spice Extracts, Herb Extract. 

Suitable for Vegetarians. Free From Artificial Flavours. 
Empty unused contents into a suitable covered container. Keep refrigerated and use within 2 days.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume source data housed in column A, put criteria header "Ingredients" & "Table of Nutritional Information" in `B1` and `C1`.

Then,

In `B2`, formula copied down :

```
=MID(LEFT($A2,FIND(C$1,$A2)-1),FIND(B$1,$A2)+LEN(B$1)+1,599)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your example cell is A1, then in another cell you can do:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1;SEARCH("Ingredients:";A1);SEARCH("Table of Nutritional Information";A1)-SEARCH("Ingredients:";A1)))
```

You will probably will have to adapt a little bit to get rid of final breaklines.

[image]

This is how it works:

1. `SEARCH("Ingredients:";A1)` will find the position of the **first** coincidence of text `Ingredientes`. returning a number. This will be starting point of extracting text with MID.
2. `SEARCH("Table of Nutritional Information";A1)` same than before, but with text `Table of Nutritional Information`. So this is the end point of extracting text
3. Step 2 - Step 1 will return how many chars you want to extract, starting at Step 1.
4. TRIM will just delete extra blanks if added. Notice that extra blanks **are not** the same than breaklines.

In this case, to get rid of final BREAKLINES, just do extra -5:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1;SEARCH("Ingredients:";A1);SEARCH("Table of Nutritional Information";A1)-5-SEARCH("Ingredients:";A1)))
```

This will return the exact output you want, but don't know if it will work with all your inputs.